# Joomla search module do not work in mobile

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla web site with a search module.
When I search ***عکاسی*** on my computer I receive 35 results, but when I search the same word on my mobile device with the Safari browser I do not receive any results at all.
I tried to search for different words, but there were no search results.
Do you guys know why this could be the case?
[Here](http://www.fotografy.ir) is my website.

Comment: The website seems to be down, now. Were you using a responsive template or a separate mobile template (like the Mobile Joomla! component)?